# magento get products only works with disabled Flat Catalog Product

Tags: magento-1.7, index, flat-catalog

we would like to check if products exists with the following code:

```
$foundProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

We only get positive results if "Use Flat Catalog Product" is disabled in the configuration.

Comment: try reindexing and recheck the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productSku, 'sku');` instead of `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);`

Comment: I don't know why, but this seems to help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Remember to mark the question as resolved,

Answer (score 1):

the only working solution for both disabled and enabled products I found here: http://magentoexplorer.com/how-load-product-by-sku-or-id-in-magento

> $_sku = 'leathershoes';
>
> $_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
>
> $_productId = $_catalog->getIdBySku($_sku);
>
> $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this on a category page, and it does work. On which page are u trying to do this, and in what code are you using $foundProduct?

Have you reindexed all indexes after enabling flat catalog? cleared all caches?
Perhaps try to run the code with all caches disabled.

Comment: I use the line in a script to modify some product data. Yes, everything was reindexed, caches cleared.

Comment: In a custom module? or existing page? what's the scope of the code? frontend/backend?